# Get item from CollectionViewSource using index number

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using CollectionViewSource as ItemSource in DataGrid

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding CollViewSource.View}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding IndexNumber}"
    ...
```

and the CollectionViewSource is bound to ObservableCollection in ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<LevelModel> mLevelSource;
public ObservableCollection<LevelModel> LevelSource
{
     get
     {
         mLevelSource = mLevelSource ?? new ObservableCollection<LevelModel>();
         return mLevelSource;
     }
}


public CollectionViewSource CollViewSource { get; set; }
```

Model

```
public class LevelModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Level_Title { get; set; }
    ...
```

In Constructor

```
CollViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
CollViewSource.Source = LevelSource;
```

I have Button inside DataGrid

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button
            Command="{Binding DataContext.ViewCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
            Content="View" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

What I want, when i click the Button .i.e ViewCommand it should fetch Level_Title or some other item by Index Number

```
private ICommand mViewCommand;
public ICommand ViewCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (mViewCommand == null)
        {
            mViewCommand = new DelegateCommand(delegate ()
            {
                int indexNumber = IndexNumber;
                //string title = // logic should go here


            });
        }
        return mViewCommand;
    }
}
```

For example when index number is 3 then it should fetch the item that exist on 3rd index

**Note:** I don't want to involve SeletedItem

Comment: Did you tried using `LevelSource[indexNumber]`?

Comment: @Dishant thanks, LevelSource[IndexedNumber].Level_Title is currect but how to fetch item from CollectionViewSource.

Comment: `LevelSource[indexNumber]` will itself fetch the item based on the index as it is bind to `CollectionViewSource`.

Comment: @Dishant thanks again, there are some reasons of using CollectionViewSource, one of them is Filtering, so when i filter LevelSource[indexNumber] will not fetch the correct item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following on your CollectionView:

```
LevelModel lm = CollViewSource.View.Cast<LevelModel>().ToArray()[indexNumber];
string title = lm.Level_Title;
```

Comment: for your kind answer, its showing error CollViewSource does not contain definition for Cast,

Comment: You have to reference Linq