# WPF ListBox SelectedIndex with grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I tried to google this question but didn't find anything.

I have WPF ListBox with a binding to the SelectedIndex, the ItemSource is a ObservableCollection with a custom class. Everything worked fine until I added grouping to the ListBox by adding a PropertyGroupDescription to the CollectionView.

Because of the grouping the visible items in the ListBox have a different order than the items in the ViewModel collection. For some reason I assumed that the SelectedIndex is always based on the ItemSource collection, but it looks like the SelectedIndex is based on the visible ListBox index.

This means that the SelectedIndex has a different meaning now and can't be used anymore in the ViewModel, because the ListBox index 0 (with grouping) could be a different item then the ViewModel index 0 (without grouping).

Is there any way to "convert" the SelectedIndex with the grouping to the index of the actual ViewModel ItemSource?

I guess the only other solution would be to bind to the SelectedItem instead of the SelectedIndex?

Comment: What is the usage of the binding on the viewmodel side? The binding target for SelectedIndex? If you only use that integer to then index for the instance of your custom class then as you say, binding to SelectedItem sounds reasonable.

Comment: Yes I only used it as a index of the source collection, I usually like to bind to index instead of adding (and binding) a public SelectedItem setter in the ViewModel, but I think in this case I will change it to SelectedItem, because the other solution (see my own answer) doesn't seem to be worth it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, after posting the question I found an other answer:
[Get item from CollectionViewSource using index number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089081/get-item-from-collectionviewsource-using-index-number)

I have to store the ICollectionView with the grouping in a variable, it will have the same order as the ListBox and can use the SelectedIndex to search in the ICollectionView instead of the original ObservableCollection.

(Or simply bind the the SelectedItem instead of dealing with the index)

Comment: You can close your question as duplicate, if answer is found